curly-curly braces - why won't this function accept an unquoted variable
Can someone help me see where I'm going wrong? I thought when using curly-curly braces in a piped function that you could call the variable without having to enclose it in "" (i.e. as a string). So where is my function going wrong:
library(tidyverse)
dat <-  structure(list(id = 1:6, 
                       var_1 = c("1,1,-11000", "1,1,1", "0,0,0", "1,1,0", "1,1,1", "1,1,1"), 
                       var_2 = c("0,0,-13000", "0,0,0", "-13000,-13000,-13000", "6,4,-13000", "0,0,0", "0,0,0"), 
                       var_3 = c("24,7,-13000", "0,0,0", "-13000,-13000,-13000", "0,0,-13000", "0,0,0", "0,0,0")), 
                  row.names = 1:6, class = "data.frame")

# Separate to wide and convert to long in one step
split_to_long <-  function(col){
  i <-  substr({{col}}, 5, 5)
  temp <-  dat |>
    select("id", {{col}}) |>
    separate_wider_delim({{col}}, ",", too_few = "align_start",
                         names = c(paste0({{col}},"_1"),
                                   paste0({{col}},"_2"),
                                   paste0({{col}},"_3"))) |>
    pivot_longer(2:4,
                 names_to = "visit",
                 values_to = paste0("var_", i),
                 names_prefix = paste0("var_", i, "_"))
  temp
}

# This works
split_to_long("var_1")

# But this doesn't
split_to_long(var_1)

This comes from another question I posted:
How to replace this for loop with purrr::map

It's because var_1 isn't an object in the environment that you're calling the function from. However, if it was an object it would get evaluated before it was sent to the function, so that wouldn't work either. If you wanted to send it as an object, not in the current environment, because you know it will be in the environment it's used in in your function, then you can tell R that by calling split_to_long(expr(var_1)). This tells R, hey, this isn't a string, it's a thing, but don't evaluate it just yet...

If you want to fully understand the dynamics, consider exploring non-standard evaluation.

If you want both to work, you can make a few modifications to your code, using the substitute function. I also suggest including a data argument to your function.
split_to_long <-  function(data, col){

  col_i <- substitute(col)
  i <-  substr(col_i, 5, 5)
  
  temp <-  data |>
    select(id, {{col}}) |>
    separate_wider_delim({{col}}, ",", too_few = "align_start",
                         names = c(paste0(col_i,"_1"),
                                   paste0(col_i,"_2"),
                                   paste0(col_i,"_3"))) |>
    pivot_longer(2:4,
                 names_to = "visit",
                 values_to = paste0("var_", i),
                 names_prefix = paste0("var_", i, "_"))
  temp
}

res1 <- split_to_long(dat, "var_1")
res2 <- split_to_long(dat, var_1)

identical(res1, res2)
[1] TRUE


Thanks. So, I want to learn something from this exercise. Fair call on including a data argument. I haven't come across substitute() before. So, by including a data argument I thought something like i <-  substr(names(data[[col]]), 5, 5) might also have worked (which is something I have used a lot in for loops), but it doesn't. Does data[[col]] not work in functions where you have supplied both a data and column argument?

Assuming you have included data as the first argument to the function, that won't work because data[[col]] returns the values (if you call the function using "var_1"). However, it would be ok if you used single brackets data[col]. Try for yourself. For the unquoted version, it won't work at all because that is not the way R works if you want to identify the name of a column in a data frame within a function. This is what substitute can do in this case. You were trying to use the same thing {{col}} for two different purposes (as a string, and as the values within the data).

I do not see why passing data as argument to a function is useful while other arguments remain hard-coded/aren't checked (early).

It’s good practice @Friede

I disagree. Without early checks or other additional arguments (for adaption) it appears unusual.

@Friede can you find a base R function that checks whether a column is within the data if both are supplied as arguments?

{{...}} only works in tidyverse functions and even then only in a quasiquotation context but substr is not even a tidyverse function much less providing a quasiquotation context.
If split_to_long is unchanged from the question write a wrapper to capture the argument using enexpr from rlang, convert it to character and then use that.
split_to_long2 <- function(col) {
  col <- as.character(enexpr(col))
  split_to_long(col)
}

split_to_long2(var_1)

or we could modify split_to_long like this where the modified lines are marked with ## below.  We have also simplified the last line marked ## .
split_to_long3 <-  function(col){
  col <- as.character(enexpr(col)) ##
  i <-  substr(col, 5, 5) 
  temp <-  dat |>
    select("id", {{col}}) |>
    separate_wider_delim({{col}}, ",", too_few = "align_start",
                         names = paste0(col, "_", 1:3)) |> ##
    pivot_longer(2:4,
                 names_to = "visit",
                 values_to = paste0("var_", i),
                 names_prefix = paste0("var_", i, "_"))
  temp
}

split_to_long3(var_1)

